# Where to get a good (non web based) XML sitemap generator?

Tags: xml, sitemap

Hi I'd like to generate am XML sitemap for a website and I can't find a good XML sitemap generator. I'm looking for a non web based app with basic functionalities that works on windows. It seems easy enough but all I could find was very old apps most of which didn't work or crashed.
Can anybody suggest one they've used and are happy with?

**edit**

I tried a lot of the tools that are available out there (online and off line), but none really suited me (i.e. something simple and that works!). So I wrote a tool to generate the sitemap myself. I'll try to make it a little bit more presentable and I'll release it for other people to use it.

Comment: Please point out which of the tools suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sitemap+generator you have tried and why they don't meet your requirements. Makes it easier for us to suggest possible alternatives.

Comment: You can leave comments on answers within your question, and also edit your question to add more detail...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try A1 Sitemap Generator? Curious to know what problems you experienced if you tried A1SG? (You have to tick off "Simplified easy mode" to view/edit options)

Answer (score 0):

There is a PEAR package for creating Sitemaps via PHP (can run from CLI):

> This package allow to create sitemap files used to describe your
>   website to help search engines indexing it. This package contains all needed
>   functions to create, read, save, add, modify and remove url, compress to
>   gzip, notify search engine and test url in the sitemap or sitemap index.

- http://pear.php.net/package/File_Sitemap

I have never used it and cannot tell if it is any good.